# how can i put the framelayout in the bottom of the application?

Tags: android, frame

i want to put a framelayout in the bottom by doing this :

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/darkblue"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bottom"
        android:textSize="30px"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
       />
  </FrameLayout>
```

But it doesn't work . It's staying in the middle of my application.

This is the whole thing :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkblue"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/back4"
            />
        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="30px"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_below="@id/first"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/banner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/chuck"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_below="@id/second"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sum"
                android:text="Summary "
                android:textSize="25px"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/s_btn"
                android:src="@drawable/next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sum"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/sum"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/blank"
                android:text=" "
                android:textSize="25px"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/sum"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/airdate"
                android:text="Air Date : "
                android:textSize="25px"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/blank"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/blank2"
                android:text=" "
                android:textSize="25px"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/airdate"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/airtime"
                android:text="Air Time : "
                android:textSize="25px"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/blank2"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkblue"
        android:id="@+id/fourth"
        android:layout_below="@id/third"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bottom"
            android:textSize="30px"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom of what? What is your parent layout? If you're using a RelativeLayout, remove the layout_gravity attribute, and add the alignParentBottom="true" attribute instead.

Comment: in the bottom of my app, kind of the pulse application

Comment: Your FrameLayout is within a parent layout. What is it? Again, if it's a RelativeLayout, the comment applies.

Comment: so what it does is resize this framelayout from the middle to the end

Comment: No, it aligns it with the bottom of the parent. Hence, alignParentBottom. You need to provide your entire XML structure. `layout_gravity` should work most likely, most likely your parent layout is not set to `fill_parent`.

Comment: i saw my mistake, i put below and alignParentBottom, it can't take both like this, thanks.

Comment: You have way too many unnecessary nested layouts. Why are you putting everything into a FrameLayout anyway? You can set the background attribute for just about anything, you don't have to add an extra layout just to add a background. Besides that, I think your problem is that in your second FrameLayout, your RelativeLayout is set to fill_parent while the FrameLayout is set to wrap_content. You should really read over some of the basic layout tutorials again, and try and optimize it a bit, it's needlessly long.

Comment: EDIT: See you found the problem. I'd still try to remove most of the FrameLayouts, they're really unnecessary unless you need things to overlap.

Comment: ok, the thing is i just wanted to make an application like this : a title border with a back button, a content part, and a bottom part .

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675796/layout-problem-how-to-place-something-on-top-and-bottom/4676049#4676049 should help you simplify it a bit, and get exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is totally correct but I'm working on an similar app with a bunch of frame layouts that get dynamically generated and had to switch to relative layouts to use the `android:layout_below="@id/some_id"` to 'stack' my layouts. I'm using fragments and it seems to be working well.

Example layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/top_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <!-- Content Foo -->

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/middle_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_layout"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <!-- Content Foo -->

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_below="@id/middle_layout"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <!-- Content Foo -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is full programmability method :

```
 EKRAN MY_EKRAN;
 context = getApplicationContext();
 MY_EKRAN = new EKRAN( contex );


 YOUR_FRAMELAYOUT =  findViewById(R.id.PUT_ID_FOR_YOUR_FRAMELAYOUT);

  YOUR_FRAMELAYOUT.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                YOUR_FRAMELAYOUT.getLayoutParams().width = MY_EKRAN.W(105);
                YOUR_FRAMELAYOUT.getLayoutParams().height = MY_EKRAN.H(10);

             //   banner.getLayoutParams().width = ( MY_EKRAN.H(10));
             //   banner.getLayoutParams().width = ( MY_EKRAN.H(10));         

                YOUR_FRAMELAYOUT.setY( MY_EKRAN.H(90) );

             // also like this 
             // YOUR_FRAMELAYOUT.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( MY_EKRAN.W(100)  ,MY_EKRAN.H(30)  ));



            }
        });
```

**Here's ekran class :**

public class EKRAN {

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
Point size_ = new Point();
static int width;
static int height;

EKRAN(Context CONTEXT_) {

    dm = CONTEXT_.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int densityDpi = dm.densityDpi;
    height = dm.heightPixels;
    width = dm.widthPixels;

}

public static int WIDTH() {

    return width;

}
public static int HEIGHT(){

    return height;

}
public int W( int PER_ ){

    return width/100*PER_;

}
public int H( int PER_   ){


    return height/100*PER_;

}

//////////////////
//extras
/////////////////
public int GET_PIX_FROM_DP ( float DP_VALUE )
{
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, DP_VALUE , dm );
}

public int GET_PIX_FROM_DP2 ( float DP_VALUE )
{
    float res = DP_VALUE * ( dm.ydpi / 160f);
    return  (int) res;
}
```

}