# LinearLayout at the top and at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have two different `LinearLayouts` inside one `LinearLayout` and I would like the first layout to be at the top and the second layout to be at the bottom. I tried with     `android:gravity="top"` but it didn't work. Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="top">
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow android:weightSum="2">
            <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
            <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:weightSum="2">
            <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
            <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="bottom">
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow android:weightSum="2">
            <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
            <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:weightSum="2">
            <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
            <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: visit this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675796/layout-problem-how-to-place-something-on-top-and-bottom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply add :

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" />
```

between your top and bottom `LinearLayout`(and remove the gravity from the parent container).

Answer (score 2):

change you parent layout as `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`, and

for top of the parent layout set following in child layout

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

and for bottom of the parent layout set following in child layout

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```